# How to fix error "could not determine running time" while performing Hyperparameter optimization via Experiment modeler in ibm watson

Tags: python, optimization, ibm-watson

I am building a time-series forecasting model using LSTM in keras. For model training I am trying to get best hyperparameter combination via HPO in Experiment modeler which I found from following article.

https://medium.com/ibm-watson/automating-and-accelerating-hyperparameter-tuning-for-deep-learning-52184944eeb4

After many attempts I got the training to run but I keep getting error saying 'could not determine running time for training run'. I check into the logs but there I see no error.
Below is the code I used, in the logs it successfully runs to the point where it prints the 'mean absolute error.'

Apart from this code, I supply the input file 'Global_temperatures_final.csv' in the bucket that stores the training data and create an experiment where I supply the hyperparameters by manually adding them in the training definition.

```
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import os
import os.path
from os import environ
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from emetrics import EMetrics
import h5py
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
# input data
if __name__=="__main__":
    input_data_folder=os.environ["DATA_DIR"]
    Global_Temp=pd.read_csv(input_data_folder+'/Global_temperature_final.csv')
# file containing hyperparameters
config_file="config.json"
if os.path.exists(config_file):
    with open(config_file,'r') as f:
        json_obj=json.load(f)
    Timesteps=json_obj["Timesteps"] 
    Ep=json_obj["Ep"]
    Neurons=json_obj["Neurons"] 
    BatchSizes=json_obj["BatchSizes"]
else:
    Timesteps=1
    Ep=1
    Neurons=1 
    BatchSizes=2
model_filename = "lstm_gtemp.h5"
# writing the train model and getting input data
if environ.get('RESULT_DIR') is not None:
    output_model_folder = os.path.join(os.environ["RESULT_DIR"], "model")
    output_model_path = os.path.join(output_model_folder, model_filename)
else:
    output_model_folder = "model"
    output_model_path = os.path.join("model", model_filename)

os.makedirs(output_model_folder, exist_ok=True)

#writing metrics
if environ.get('JOB_STATE_DIR') is not None:
    tb_directory = os.path.join(os.environ["JOB_STATE_DIR"], "logs", "tb", "test")
else:
    tb_directory = os.path.join("logs", "tb", "test")

os.makedirs(tb_directory, exist_ok=True)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=tb_directory)
def getCurrentSubID():
    if "SUBID" in os.environ:
        return os.environ["SUBID"]
    else:
        return None

class HPOMetrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.emetrics = EMetrics.open(getCurrentSubID())

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        train_results = {}
        test_results = {}

        for key, value in logs.items():
            if 'val_' in key:
                test_results.update({key: value})
            else:
                train_results.update({key: value})

        print('EPOCH ' + str(epoch))
        self.emetrics.record("train", epoch, train_results)
        self.emetrics.record(EMetrics.TEST_GROUP, epoch, test_results)

    def close(self):
        self.emetrics.close()
Global_Temp['Date']=pd.to_datetime(Global_Temp['Date'])
Global_Temp.set_index('Date',drop=True,inplace=True)
Training_data,Testing_data=train_test_split(Global_Temp,test_size=0.1,shuffle=False)
def Data_preperation(Data,BatchSize,Timesteps):
    #For the Stateful LSTM we need to have [(length of training_data)-timesteps] exactly divisible by the batch-size so that 
    #we can divide the whole training data set into batchs to be supplied for training the model
    length=int((len(Data)-2*Timesteps)/BatchSize)*BatchSize
    #Clipping the training data-set
    Data=Data[:length+Timesteps*2]
    # reshape the data for feature scaling
    Data_1=Data['Monthly_Temperature'].values.reshape(-1,1)
    # Feature scaling
    Scaling=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    Data_scaled=Scaling.fit_transform(np.float64(Data_1))
    # Create x,y data for LSTM training or prediction
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(Timesteps,length+Timesteps):
        x.append(Data_scaled[i-Timesteps:i,0])
        y.append(Data_scaled[i:i+Timesteps,0])
    #Reshaping for LSTM with dimensions [Length X Timesteps X 1]
    #By creating strips of time-series of size of timesteps
    x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)
    x=np.reshape(x,(x.shape[0],x.shape[1],1))
    y=np.reshape(y,(y.shape[0],y.shape[1],1))
    return x,y
x_train,y_train=Data_preperation(Training_data,BatchSize=BatchSizes,Timesteps=Timesteps)
x_test,y_test=Data_preperation(Testing_data,BatchSize=BatchSizes,Timesteps=Timesteps)
input_layer=Input(batch_shape=(BatchSizes,Timesteps,1))
lstm_layer=LSTM(Neurons,stateful=True,return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
output_layer=Dense(units=1)(lstm_layer)
model=Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=output_layer)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mae')

hpo = HPOMetrics()

#Because the LSTM network is stateful therefore I reset the internal states after each epoch.
for e in range(Ep):
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,shuffle=False,epochs=1,batch_size=BatchSizes,verbose=0,callbacks=[tensorboard, hpo])
    model.reset_states()
hpo.close()
def Model_Forecast(x,model,BatchSize):
    yhat=model.predict(x,batch_size=BatchSize)
    return yhat
def Model_evaluation(y,yhat):
    MAE=mean_absolute_error(np.reshape(y,y.shape[0]*y.shape[1],1),np.reshape(yhat,yhat.shape[0]*yhat.shape[1],1))
    return MAE 
y_pred=Model_Forecast(x_test,model=model,BatchSize=BatchSizes)
MAE_score=Model_evaluation(y_test,y_pred)
print('Mean absolute error ',MAE_score)
# save the model
model.save(output_model_path)
```